# how to show high level overview of a slideshow presentation in powerpoint or google slides

Tags: slideshow, powerpoint, google-docs

I recently attended a lecture where the speaker's slide show had a header through the entire presentation showing the high level grouping of the slides and with a dot representing how far through the overall presentation we were. I liked this style a lot and am now trying to emulate it but cannot seem to find any tutorials or even come up with the right keywords to search on this. is there a specific name for this and how do i accomplish this in PowerPoint or Google slides preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i corresponded with the presenter who i was trying to emulate and am going to consider this case closed because they used beamer and latex to make the slides which is how the header with "section dots" was generated. in case anyone is wondering they used the theme warsaw and the final result should look something like this example: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=23331 but with all the sections and section dots being there and cycled through as you click through your presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching on

powerpoint breadcrumb

Comment: that looks like the right track but i am still not seeing if there is a way to have either software generate these for me or how to add it in if this functionality exists in these softwares?

Comment: There's no built-in functionality for it.  You'd have to write (or find someone who's written or hire someone to write) code to do it for you.  It can certainly be done.  There's a very simple example on the PPT FAQ site that I maintain:  Add a "thermometer" progress bar to each slide
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00597_Add_a_-thermometer-_progress_bar_to_each_slide.htm

Answer (score 1):

I made a little PowerPoint Add- In to generate a quick Breadcrumb header for your slides. You still have to set the colors, but it's really fast if you don't want to use the Master:

[Simple Breadcrumb Generator For PowerPoint](https://github.com/ninijay/simple-breadcrumb-generator-for-PowerPoint)

Comment: That link is dead! :(

Comment: yes indeed. but in posted the code in another post...
sorry mario. your princess is in another castle